# Plans to extend Gazebo world editor?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
are any plans to extend the Gazebo world editor in the short term future? To support loading of arbitrary mesh files (through drop-down menu for instance) and saving of the created world configurations for instance?

D.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44459/plans-to-extend-gazebo-world-editor?/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1420 on 2012-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess there are plans, at least according to the [version 1.0 design specification](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo/Version_1.0_Design_Specification).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2012-09-24**:
Thx again Lenz, I overlooked that. Not sure marking this as a correct answer does not work for me.

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2012-09-24**:
Ahh, wow, but also just realized that that specification is about 1.5 years old. Is anyone from the Gazebo core development around and could confirm that it is still in place?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-09-24**:
hi there, yes we are specifically working on improving the ui.  as of now on dev branch off mercurial, one should be able to click-spawn object in gui, move it around and save the world file.  also working on extending ui in various ways, e.g. save/resume state, etc..  we'll keep everyone posted.

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2012-09-24**:
John if you need beta testers/help with the code let us know where the repo is and how we could help. Sounds very, very interesting.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2012-09-24**:
I'm also offering help with code/testing.